# what is a univariate constant?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I've come across a constant so called 'univariate constant'. The one obtained when integrating a partial derivative such as C(y). Is is like a function?

Comment: it is a constant that depends on $y$ but not on the variable that was integrated against ($x$, I presume).

Comment: So it is a function of y?

Comment: yeah. so you are right that it makes little sense to call it a constant

Comment: Thanks. You could write it as an answer and I will mark it if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a function of one variable, $f(x)$, and you want to determine a function $F(x)$ such that $F(x)'=f(x)$. You will notice 
that if $F_0(x)$ is a solution, then $F_0(x)+C$ is one as well, for any value of $C$. Thus one says that the *antiderivative* of $f(x)$ is $F(x)+C$.

In higher dimensions, if you are given $f(x,y)$ and you want to determine a function $F(x,y)$ such that $\frac{d}{dx}F(x,y)=f(x,y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, you will similarly see that if $F_0(x,y)$ is a solution, then $F_0(x,y)+C(y)$ is one as well, no matter how you choose the *function* $C(y)$. Thus, the word *constant* that your professor uses is based on the equivalent analysis in one dimensions, but you are right that one should instead better speak of a *function that is independent of $x$*, or *a function that is constant in $x$*.